# how to add image in gwt uibinder

Tags: gwt

I have a UIBinder java class in gwt which contain a label with some text like

```
 Label img = new Label();
 img.setText("<img src=h.png></img>") or some other Html tag like div
```

and add this label in HTMLPanel

```
HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel;
html.add(img,"img");
```

now I have a table in uibinder xml like

```
 <table align="center" cellspacing="20px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>image</td>
                            <td id="image"></td>
                        </tr>
    <table>
```

but here I am getting a string

```
"<img src=h.png></img>"
```

not a image please some one help me..

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use Label widget if you need an Image. If you use an ImageResource, you can do:

```
// Link to your ClientBundle with ImageResource methods
<ui:with type="com.myPackage.client.icons.Icons" field="icon" />

<g:Image ui:field="myImage" resource="{icon.myImage}" />
```

If you don't need this image to do anything, then you can simply use regular HTML:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <img src="h.png" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```